# After installing Ubuntu Windows-8 is gone, How to get back access?

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, migration

Today I installed Ubuntu on my computer, and I thought, It would install Ubuntu beneath the already installed Windows installation.

But I cannot access and start Windows any more.

Can someone please explain, how to check if Windows is still there and accessible?
Or if not, How I could recover as much as possible from my Windows installation?

Comment: You need to check if you really erased your windows, please tell us what you did in order to install ubuntu.

Comment: just to be clearer: do your remember what was your choice at this point? http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/1187/u/img/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop/image-installdesktoplongtermsupport-4.jpg

Comment: please check if there still is a partition with windows, by checking on the console this: `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: @Stronglion It was hard to understand exactly what you asked. I've noticed this post was recently edited. Does the edit correctly express what you mean? If it doesn't (or if you otherwise want to ask it differently), I recommend you [edit] this again. Originally you used the term "windows things," and I'm not sure the recent edit captures your thoughts. Was your goal to have a dual-boot system where you can choose between Windows and Ubuntu when you start your computer and where both systems work? Or are you asking about accessing files from the Windows system in Ubuntu? Or something else?